# Error al inicializar un fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

Gente me da este pequeño error al inicializar el Fragment.   BlankFragment es mi Fragment. dice q no es compatible la clase Fragment con la de BlankFragment extendiendo esta de Fragment

```
private void seleccionarItem(MenuItem itemDrawer) {
    Fragment fragmentoGenerico = null;
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    switch (itemDrawer.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_camera:
            *********fragmentoGenerico = new BlankFragment();*******
            break;
        case R.id.nav_gallery:
            // Fragmento para la sección Cuenta


            break;
        case R.id.nav_manage:
            // Fragmento para la sección Categorías

            break;
        case R.id.nav_send:
            // Iniciar actividad de configuración

            break;
    }
    if (fragmentoGenerico != null) {
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.contenedor_principal, fragmentoGenerico)
                .commit();
    }
    // Setear título actual
    setTitle(itemDrawer.getTitle());
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(itemDrawer.getIcon());

}
```

Comment: En primer lugar no veo el error del logcat pero, suponiendo que es el típico error podría ser que tu fragment es de android.app.Fragment; y no de android.support.v4.app.Fragment; Considero que deberias dar mas información

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes asegurar que `Fragment` use el import:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
...
...
...
Fragment fragmentoGenerico = null;
```

y `BlankFragment` debe extender de `Fragment` y tambien usar el mismo import.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
...
...
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
```

`FragmentManager` y `FragmentTransaction` deben hacer uso de los import

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

El problema se debe a que seguramente estas usando el import incorrecto en este caso que es:

```
import android.app.Fragment
```

Comment: Ya resolvi, me sirvio de mucha  ayuda graciass